# Choose which word in a paragraph rests at the end of a page

Tags: line-breaking

I have a situation where I am trying to set out the text of another document in latex. I have replicated the dimensions and chosen a font that is almost the same. The only thing I am having trouble with is where a paragraph runs to a new page. The last word on the page is not lining up. Is it possible to do something like this:

```
  A paragraph with some text, and this is another bit of
text and I want this to run to the end of the line |---->

------  (page break)

\noindent
like this so it appears that the word 'line'
was the last word on the page.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use just use `\linebreak` at the point that you want the line to break, then most likely the page break will look after itself. If you also want to force a page break at that point use `\pagebreak\linebreak` (it that order).

Of course this assumes that the text is long enough that line breaking the paragraph has a feasible linebreak at that point. If you have  three-word paragraph and force a linebreak after the second word, TeX will try to accommodate the instruction, but the result will not be good.